# Dealloc in NavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

in a UINavigationController, when es dealloc called? In my app, i have 4 ViewController:

View1Controller->View2Controller->View3Controller->View4Controller

If im in View2Controller and push Back Button to go to View1Controller, dealloc in View2Controller is called. But if im in View1Controller and go to View2Controller, dealloc never called in View1Controller.

It´s is OK? Or Its a leak?

Thanks.

EDIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pushing and popping view controllers on a UINavigationViewController stack acts like a stack in the general sense.  If you had a stack that contains numbers, pushing 2, then 36 would give you a stack of 2 numbers, you wouldn't expect the 2 to disappear.  Pushing a view controller is exactly the same, when you push ViewController2, you wouldn't expect ViewController1 to disappear.

However, with popping it's different.  If you pop off the 36 you wouldn't expect the 36 to still exist.  Same with view controllers.  Pop off ViewController2 and it will get dealloced when the user interface displays ViewController1 views.

Comment: and View1Controller never will be deallocated?

Comment: @AlbertoJuarez rootViewController will not get deallocated.

Comment: and all de objects with property retain that are there? is better dont put objects with retain in rootViewController?

Comment: Those objects will exist as long as the rootViewController exists, which will exist as long as the UINavigationController exists (unless it is retained somewhere else, then longer). See the edit to my answer for a bit more clarification.

Comment: Please study the memory-management guide from Apple and really understand the retain/release/autorelease system.  Your whole understanding of iOS programming will be based on this understanding.

Answer (score 1):

This also has to do with retain count. If you pop off a view controller and you don't reference it in any other way then the reference count will go to zero and iOS will likely dealloc it shortly after. If you are referencing it in some way ,with a member in an owning class for instance, and the reference count was not brought to zero when it was popped off the navigation stack then it would not be deallocated at that time.

Answer (score 1):

Check for NSTimer in your view controller. If NSTimer exist then invalidate it in viewWillDisappear or viewDidDisappear of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Pushing a viewcontroller onto a navigation stack does not unload / dealloc the view controller you are coming from. It still exists in the stack underneath the new one. Popping from a view controller will de-allocate it if it has not been retained anywhere else (with a strong pointer).

edit:
Why would View4Controller be reacting in any way to something that happens in View2Controller? From the way you described it, it shouldn't even be on the navigation stack at all at that point.

**edit2:**

One thing to remember is that when you push something onto a navigation stack, its retain count will go up by 1. If you pop something off of a navigation stack, its retain count will go down by 1. As a general rule, when an object's retain count reaches 0, it will be dealloced.

When **pushing**, the item you are pushing from (now underneath what you just pushed) does not have its retain count changed. It is still being retained by the navigation controller and therefore will not be dealloced, but instead just disappear. When **popping**, the retain count for the popped item does drop, and if it becomes 0, it will be dealloced.

Comment: For navigation between views, i do:    Entrada *varEntrada = [[Entrada alloc] initWithNibName:@"Entrada" bundle:nil];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:varEntrada animated:YES];
    [varEntrada release];

Comment: what is that in response to? That is the normal way to do this and does not conflict with anything I said.